# rails email sending code needs days + 2 for tomorrow, why is that?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a loop to select 'LibrarySwaps' for tomorrow.

This works, but not when I set days_ahead default to 1 (it returns records with todays date).

Why do I need to add 2 to the date to get a day than is only 1 day in the future?
I am doing this 11am EST so this is not a time zone issue with that and UTC both being  the same day...  I thought maybe 'cos one side has a time component and the other doesn't but nope, I'm using date() for the sql and Date + 1.days for the ruby.  I may switch to (one date minus the other date) and look at the result.

Thanks!

```
Returns Tomorrows (uses 2):
  def self.find_future_swaps(days_ahead=2)
    @upcoming_swaps = LibrarySwap.all(:conditions => ['date(suggested_date) = ?',Date.today + days_ahead.day ])
  end

Returns Todays (uses 1):
  def self.find_future_swaps(days_ahead=1)
    @upcoming_swaps = LibrarySwap.all(:conditions => ['date(suggested_date) = ?',Date.today + days_ahead.day ])
  end
```

Comment: I'd recommend popping into a `rails console` and punching in `Date.today`, `Date.today + 1.day`, and `Date.today + 2.days` to see what results you get. It may be a timezone issue or something. Can you post the output of those three lines in the console?

Comment: Hi dmarkow, thanks!, I get:
ruby-1.8.7-p302 :001 > Date.today
 => Fri, 29 Apr 2011 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 :002 > Date.today + 1.day
 => Sat, 30 Apr 2011 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 :003 > Date.today + 2.days
 => Sun, 01 May 2011 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 :004 >

Comment: if i st it to =1 i get
  LibrarySwap Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `library_swaps` WHERE (date(suggested_date) = '2011-04-30') ORDER BY swap_complete

Comment: but then There is a book swap scheduled on 2011-04-29 20:00 for your book: 

but then There is a book swap scheduled on 2011-04-29 20:00 for your book:

Comment: This is one of the two mailer codes, sorry can't format here      # Holder
      r = MyMailer.create_swap_holder(
          swap.book.book_name, swap.suggested_date.to_s, swap.book.user.username, swap.user.username, swap.book.user.email, swap.suggested_location)
          #book_name           swap_date            From                     To                  Emaail(deliver_to)         Where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is likely storing your `suggested_date` field in UTC. So an entry from 10pm on 4/29 would actually be stored as 3am on 4/30 (assuming you're in the Eastern timezone).

You can do this to add the offset to the times you're searching for:

```
    @upcoming_swaps = LibrarySwap.all(:conditions => ['date(convert_tz(suggested_date,'+00:00','-05:00')) = ?',Date.today + days_ahead.day ])
```

Comment: Oh, ok... earlier you said it showed "2011-04-29 20:00" which would be stored in the database as "2011-04-30 01:00". Can you look at the raw data in the database for the rows that are showing up that you think shouldn't, to see what the `suggested_date` field looks like in MySQL?

Comment: i see now, I thought the issue was the current time (which was around noon) so the off-set of 4 or 5 hours wouldn't affect it, but now I see if the time of the data is in the evening, it may be seen as the next day.  I will have to do some more digging.

Comment: yes, I confirmed it, it wasn't the difference in the current time, it was the difference in the 'suggested date' field. Thanks!

Comment: The code I ended up using is:
    @upcoming_swaps = LibrarySwap.all(:conditions => [' date(DATE_ADD(suggested_date, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) = ?',Date.today + days_ahead ])

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's a 4-hour difference during Daylight Saving (March-November) and a 5-hour difference during standard time (November-March).